# Does the collector voltage have to be greater than the emitter voltage by few tenths of a volt for an NPN transitor

Tags: transistors, amplifier, npn, semiconductors, solid-state-devices

For an NPN transistor, does the collector voltage have to be greater than the emitter voltage by few tenths of a volt for it to be in active state? If yes what is the reason?

Also it says greater by a few tenths. "A few tenths" is slighly vague. Do we have any standard how much more Vc needs to be?

In the *Practical Electronics for Inventors*, for the active state there are 2 rules. It is the 1st rule I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: Yes, for the reason stated -- it doesn't work. Note that it is possible to swap E and C on a transistor, which puts it into "reverse active" mode, which is less effective than the normal "forward active" mode. But it still won't work if there isn't at least a couple hundred millivolts across C and E in either direction.

Comment: By "at least" a few tenths

Answer (score 2):

If Vc is too close to Ve, the transistor is saturated, not in forward (or reverse) active mode.

The transistor's datasheet will have a quantity listed called the *saturation voltage*, \$V_{ce,sat}\$. With a collector-emitter voltage below \$V_{ce,sat}\$ (and adequate base current or gate voltage to otherwise put it into active mode), the transistor is in saturation mode. With a collector-emitter voltage *significantly* below \$V_{ce,sat}\$, the transistor can be considered more as two diodes than a transistor. This voltage is usually a few tenths of a volt for small BJTs, but it varies between transistors. In Darlington and Sziklai pairs, it's always at least one diode drop, a major drawback of the gain-enhancing topologies. In some very high-power BJTs and IGBTs, it can be over a volt.

\$V_{ce,sat}\$ is actually not a constant, and varies logarithmically with collector current. It can generally be considered a constant for most purposes, however; just be aware that it will be lower than the datasheet value if you operate at much lower collector currents than the test value used in the datasheet, and higher if you operate at much higher currents.

Comment: I disagree with “ Vce… varies logarithmically with collector current”. At this point hFE is very low Rce =Vce/Ic is fairly constant and Vce rises linearly with Ic. Rce might reduce slightly with rising current but not exponentially. That occurs at the start of saturation for Vce=1 to 2V

Answer (score 1):

Yes because when Vc < Ve for NPN with Vb forward biased the collector base junction is now forward biased incorrectly and shunts all current gain to 1.

As Vce reduces towards 0 Vcb is becoming forward biased and hFE reduces towards 10% of the max hFE at the rated Vce(sat) @Ic because that is a standard using Ic/Ib=10 for this condition.

Thus it can be said that saturation at low currents begins at Vce<0.6 but at max current there exists a junction resistance Rce=Vce/Ic such that at max current saturation actually starts for Vce<2V typically.  This is important when considering linearity and 2nd harmonic distortion as well as clipping the negative sine peak at extremes.

Comment: Thx . it says greater by few tenths.Few tenths is slighly vague. Do we have any standard how much more.?

Comment: @user31058 - In a general text like that it cannot be specified more precisely - it varies between transistors and operating conditions, temperature etc. It could be as low as a few mv in some specialized devices. As the other answer says - look in the datasheet for the specific device.

Comment: @user31058. A few tenths of a volt for a low current 100mA saturation current implies the Rce value is “a few ohms” The Rce value is always inverse to the designed power rating of the chip typ Rce = 50%/Pd [ohms] max (my Rule of Thumb) , with a wide tolerance . So that is why it is rated for a few tenths of a volt. Yet if conducting only 1uA , it would be well under 50mV due to differences in doping large for Vbe vs Vcb

Answer (score 1):

You are hung up on quantifying the "few tenths". But there is another way to look at this. In order for an npn transistor to be in its saturated mode, both the base emitter junction and the base collector junction must be forward biased. This is often given as the true definition of saturation. Saturation is the mode we use when we are trying to just turn on some load. We are trying to get Vce (NPN) as low as possible so that the transistor approximates a mechanical switch.

In saturation Vbc will be a bit lower than Vbe because of the geometry and doping concentrations in the various regions and there will be net current flow from collector to emitter (in NPN). So the point is that if you maintain the bias conditions and current flow, you will get your few tenths of a volt. It is not like you need to do some calculations to avoid accidentally letting the voltage get too low. You drive the base hard into forward bias, and the transistor will pull the collector down as low as it can, allowing maximum current to flow through the load. Once the collector drops below the base voltage, you are in saturation, and base current will start to increase (if you hold the base voltage constant).

All of this just happens. As long as you drive the base hard, you don't need to worry about accidentally letting Vce get too low.

There is also active mode to consider. But in active mode, the base collector junction is reverse biased. So Vce will be larger than in the saturation case. There is also reverse active  mode, but I won't go into it. You can search on this site to find out more about reverse active mode.